# Flutter : google_maps_flutter consume high memory

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

I am using **google_maps_flutter 0.5.24** to show maps on Flutter projects for Android and iOS,

In that, I have facing issues related to high memory consumption and application crashes on iOS and Android both.

**Here is the scenario of a crash:**

I am using a map on multiple screens whereas I am switch screen multiple times on map around 10 times and application crash because of high memory consumption.

I have tested in iOS instrument control that memory goes to more the 1GB and crash there is no releasing pattern for the map, can anyone let me know how to handle this scenario.

**Here is an example that crash on iOS and Android both.**

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example

Thanks.

Comment: Hardly anyone can help you without looking at your code. So always try to post your code with your question.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi That simple map added on the screen, nothing else, as I have tested separately.

Comment: Your code may be simple but there may be memory leaks problem.

Comment: Edited question added an example.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are seeing something similar to this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35243

Comment: any update on this issue ?. I think i get the same issue trying to add maps in Listview